# Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory in ubuntu wsl

Tags: php, node.js, docker, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Issue

```
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\test\example-app'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

How to solve this issue

I tried

`rm -rf node_modules` and remove the packages json and install it again but the error still persist

Comment: you should start npm on you wsl not on the windows host

Comment: I already tried it in WSL but the error still persist while I`m trying to run this command npm run dev @Jens

Comment: which error do you get when you call it in ubuntu?

Comment: Yes in ubuntu WSL this kind of weird because I already install the laravel application then I'm trying to run the npm run dev to beautify those UI pages @Jens

Comment: In addtion my setup is docker in windows 11

Comment: I think you mix a lot of technologies that yo don't understand.

Comment: Yes because I'm trying to practice vite in laravel @Jens